# Scientific libraries for Lua?

Tags: python, lua, scipy, scientific-computing, torch

Are there any scientific packages for Lua comparable to Scipy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is the basis for one in [Numeric Lua](http://numlua.luaforge.net/).

Comment: What about a plotting library for Lua?

Comment: I wrote a Lua wrapper for Dislin for Lua 5.1, but there are probably better options today. A Google search for "lua plot" shows a few options: [lua-gnuplot](https://luarocks.org/modules/luarocks/lua-gnuplot), [Torch](http://www.lighting-torch.com/2015/08/24/plotting-with-torch7/), and [lua_flot](http://stevedonovan.github.io/lua-flot/flot-lua.html).

Answer (score 12):

You should try **[Torch7](http://www.torch.ch)** ([github](https://github.com/andresy/torch)).

Torch7 has a very nice and efficient vector/matrix/tensor numerical library
with a Lua front-end. It also has a bunch of functions for computer vision
and machine learning.

It's pretty recent but getting better quickly.

Comment: While Torch7 is for general use, currently most of the work has been done for neural networks. Also, while it does support gnuplot, there isn't anything like matplotlib for it. I use Torch7, but still go back to Python for analysis and plotting. Hopefully that can change.

Comment: Also not officially supported on Windows?

Comment: there is https://github.com/facebook/iTorch which uses ipython plotting backed

Answer (score 7):

One can always use [Lunatic Python](http://labix.org/lunatic-python) and access scipy inside lua.

```
> require("python")
> numpy = python.import("numpy")
> numpy.array ... etc ..
```

Comment: And also, you could try [lutorpy](https://github.com/imodpasteur/lutorpy) for converting between lua/torch and numpy array, so you can use scipy with torch.

Answer (score 5):

You have some options:

- [Numeric Lua](http://numlua.luaforge.net/) - C module for Lua 5.1/5.2, provides matrices, FFT, complex numbers and others
- [GSL Shell](http://www.nongnu.org/gsl-shell/) - Modification of Lua (supports Lua libraries) with a nice syntax. Provides almost everything that Numeric Lua does, plus ODE solvers, plotting capabilities, and other nice things. Has a great documentation.
- [SciLua](http://www.scilua.org/) - Pure LuaJIT module. Aims to be a complete framework for scientific computing in Lua. Provides vectors and matrices, random numbers / distributions, optimization, others. Still in early development.
- [Lua Numerical Algorithms](https://bitbucket.org/lucashnegri/lna) - Pure LuaJIT module (uses blas/lapack via LuaJIT FFI). Provides matrices / linear algebra, FFT, complex numbers, optimization algorithms, ODE solver, basic statistics (+ PCA, LDA), and others. Still in early development, but has a somewhat complete documentation and test suits.

Comment: Numeric Lua is deprecated in favour of torch7

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if it is comparable to Scipy, but there is [GSL Shell](http://www.nongnu.org/gsl-shell/) which is based on LuaJIT and GNU Scientific Library, which offers many numerical algorithms and vector/matrix linear algebra operations.

Answer (score 2):

There's a Numpy-like extension for Lua which runs without dependencies at

https://github.com/jzrake/lunum

In the future it will provide FFT's and linear algebra like Numpy+Scipy. Presently it supports numeric array manipulation like in Numpy.